# Match based on a vector in R

Tags: r, vector, match

Let's say we have a dataframe that contains individuals that are part of a group, e.g.: in the first column an ID, in the second column a time indicator, and in the third column are the ID's of the group members.

```
Data <- data.frame(TICKER = rep(rep(c(1, 2, 3), each = 3), 2),
               TIME = c(rep(2012, 9), rep(2013, 9)),
               PEER = c(2, 500, 503,
                        1, 3, 504,
                        507, 508, 2,
                        2, 500, 503,
                        1, 3, 504,
                        507, 508, 509))
```

What I would like to achieve is that I get a fourth column with indicators that indicate if individuals have each other in the same group. That is, the following output:

```
ID    TIME    PEER    INDICATOR
1     2012    2       1
1     2012    500     0
1     2012    503     0
2     2012    1       1
2     2012    3       1
2     2012    504     0
3     2012    507     0
3     2012    508     0
3     2012    2       1
1     2013    2       1
1     2013    500     0
1     2013    503     0
2     2013    1       1
2     2013    3       0 [since individual 3 does not have individual 2 anymore]
2     2013    504     0
3     2013    507     0
3     2013    508     0
3     2013    509     0
```

What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick two-liner trick:

```
row_match <- apply(Data, 1, function(dr) paste0(sort(dr), collapse="_"))

Data$INDICATOR <- as.numeric(duplicated(row_match) | duplicated(row_match, fromLast = T))

> Data
   TICKER TIME PEER INDICATOR
1       1 2012    2         1
2       1 2012  500         0
3       1 2012  503         0
4       2 2012    1         1
5       2 2012    3         1
6       2 2012  504         0
7       3 2012  507         0
8       3 2012  508         0
9       3 2012    2         1
10      1 2013    2         1
11      1 2013  500         0
12      1 2013  503         0
13      2 2013    1         1
14      2 2013    3         0
15      2 2013  504         0
16      3 2013  507         0
17      3 2013  508         0
18      3 2013  509         0
```

Comment: Thx, feel free to select as answer ;)